# "An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source" thrown when calling MessageBox.Show()

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm extremely new to WPF and I have the following problem:

I'm trying to develop a practice application to help me have control of my budgets.

I have a class Partida like so:

```
public class Partida
{
    public delegate void PartidaChangedHandler(Partida p);
    public event PartidaChangedHandler OnPartidaChanged;
    private ObservableCollection<PartidaEntry> content;

    public Partida()
    {
        content = new ObservableCollection<PartidaEntry>();
        content.CollectionChanged += PartidaEntriesCollectionChanged;

    }

    public void PartidaEntriesCollectionChanged(object s, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (OnPartidaChanged != null)
        {
            OnPartidaChanged(this);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm displaying the `content` collection with a Datagrid, but I need to know when the `content` collection of this class changed and fire the `OnPartidaChanged` event.

Outside of the class (in MainWindow) I hook up to the `OnPartidaChanged` event like so:

```
p.OnPartidaChanged += (Partida ppp) =>
{
    int foo = 5;
    MessageBox.Show("A partida has changed!");
};
```

When I add a new row within the DataGrid, the event fires correctly, however as soon as MessageBox gets executed I get an `InvalidOperationException` with the following message:

> An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source.

Any idea how can a fix that problem without losing the ability to listen to the ObservableCollection's CollectionChanged event and firing OnPartidaChanged after that event?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: Also, I would like to know what on earth MessageBox has to do with ItemControl... why is the exception firing if MessageBox only displays a simple box! :S

Comment: can you post the xaml of your ItemsControl?

Comment: I found another question here with the exact same problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120504/wpf-add-item-to-datagrid-bound-to-observablecollection-exception). The selected answer was simply to remove MessageBox.Show(), in fact they said to remove the whole CollectionChanged event handler. However the don't actually solve the problem!

Comment: @FjjF how does my linked answer not solve your problem? does the exception still occur after removing the `MessageBox.Show()` call? Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer in [WPF add item to datagrid bound to observablecollection exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19120504) explains clearly exactly what is happening: the event handler is being called while the operation that is changing the collection is in progress, and calling `MessageBox.Show()` gives the dispatcher message-handling loop a chance to start processing messages again. This causes re-entrancy that is incompatible with the way WPF works: the collection-changing operation has not been completely resolved, but the UI is being given a chance to try to run the logic that should not be run until *after* that operation has been completely resolved.

In other words, just as the exception states, the control is in an inconsistent state, because it was allowed to do some processing that should not have occurred until after it was completely done dealing with the collection changing.

I grant that the advice in the other answer is not terribly compelling. It is reasonable advice as far as it goes, but offers no real alternatives.

In your scenario, without changing anything else about your implementation, one obvious solution is to defer the message box until after the collection-changing operation has been completely resolved. You can do this by using the `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync()` method to defer execution of the call to `MessageBox.Show()`:

```
p.OnPartidaChanged += (Partida ppp) =>
{
    int foo = 5;
    Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => MessageBox.Show("A partida has changed!"));
};
```

Of course, there is the question as to whether showing a message box is really the best way to handle the event. It's not really clear from the limited information in your question why your event handler looks the way it does. If you are sure that showing a message box every time the collection changes is really the right thing to do, the above should resolve your problem.

But you might want to consider alternative means of presenting the information to the user, such as displaying it in a status field in the UI, or even providing some kind of log of events e.g. in a multi-line text box or list-box. These kinds of approaches will generally involve data-binding that fit within the normal flow of event and data handling in WPF, and would work as synchronous code without running into the issue you're seeing here.